# Working with files & FOR loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

*My task is: in every language is n most used words. A boy after d days is leaving for Sweden. Wanting to understand Swedish, the first day he learns z words and the each following day k words more than a day before. Write a program, which would check if a boy will successfully will learn n words during d days.*

*Let's say that he needs to learn 100 words. He has 20 days. The first day he learned 5 words. Each following day he learned 1 words more than a day before.*

*In this case **answer** should be: **yes** (he will successfully will learn it during 20 days), and **11** (during 11 days he will learn 100 words).*

I have a code written.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


int n, d=0, k, z;



ofstream fr("Rezults.txt");
ifstream fd("Data.txt");
fd>>n>>d>>z>>k;


        int learned_words = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<d; i++){
            learned_words += z;
            z = z+k;
        }

        if(n<=learned_words) {
            fr<<"Yes"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            fr<<"No"<<endl;

        }

    z=z-d; d=0;
    for(int m=0; m<=n; m+=z, z+=k, d++) {}

    cout << "You need " << d << " days to learn " << n << " words";

fd.close();

fr<<d;


fr.close();


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you asking, instead of simply trying and running your code?

Comment: You mean is it possible to count, rather than compute `n+1-z`? Yes, make a new variable `count` and perform `for (i=z, count=0; i<=n; i=i+1, count++)`. Did you apply any thought to the problem before posting?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking at all, sorry. What do you mean by "count numbers"?

Comment: I took it to mean he wants the sum of z through n. Guess we need some clarification.

Comment: @mah I have applied a task given above.

Comment: Variables d and z have wrong values before the last loop. d should be zero and z should be in it's original value. The first loop changes z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple function solves the problem in the beginning of your question:

```
// z : the number of words learned during the first day
// k : this much more we learn after every day 
// (i.e first day we learn z words, then z+k, then z+k+k etc.)
// d : this many days we have time to learn
// n: this many words we should learn

bool solve(int z, int d, int k, int n) {

    int learned_words = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<d; i++){
        learned_words += z;
        z = z+k;
    }

    if(n<=learned_words) { 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To answer your question about loops, I think the following very simple loop would work:

```
int n = 100;
int z = 5;
int k = 1;
int d = 0;

for(int m=0; m<n; m+=z, z+=k, d++) {}

cout << "You need " << d << " days to learn " << n << " words";
```

Here the loop will get executed the minimal number of times needed to learn those n words. The variable d counts the days needed and must be declared before the loop. m counts how many words we have learned.

Comment: @Parvizal note that the answer should be 11 days are needed to learn 100 words. If I apply Your given loop, I get 24 days. This is incorrect.

Comment: Strange. I tested my loop and I get "You need 11 days to learn 100 words" printed on my screen.

Comment: @Parvizal Well, if I run only the one you has written for me, it works. But if I put it in my code, it gives me 24. May You know why?

Comment: I wrote a comment to your post. Just before the last loop you should have d = 0 and z should be back in it's original value. The very first loop changes the value of z.

Comment: Do I have to write z=z-d; d=0 before the last loop and the code will be correct? If I write so, it works.

Comment: With those changes it works because you have added d to z in the very first loop. k=1 so every execution of loop's body adds 1 to z.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply count the loop by using the for loop in this way:

```
 for (i=z; i<=n; i++)
    {


    }

cout<< i << endl;
```

You can simply see the variable "i"'s value right after the loop

Answer (score 0):

Despite having `for loop` in the title, there's no requirement for the loop in the task and no reason to actually use it here (unless you're limited to integer arithmetic).

It would be much easier to simply compute days needed to learn `n` words (it's simple quadratic equation) and compare it with `d`.

Number of words (`y`) learnt during first `x` days is:
`y = z * x + k * x * (x-1)/2`. So just solve this equation for `y = n`.

I'd do something like: (variables `a` and `b` are coefficients of the quadratic equation).

```
const double a = k/2.0;
const double b = z-k/2.0;
const double days_needed = -b + ::sqrt(b*b + 4 * a * n)/(2.0 * a);
std::cout << (days_needed <= d ?"yes":"no") << ", you need " << ::ceil(days_needed) << "days\n";
```